# How to plot a bar chart with a range of values on one axis and the sum of corresponding values of rows of other column in that range on other axis

Tags: pandas, dataframe, matplotlib

Suppose I have similar data like below, which has four columns. I want to divide column ['R'] into ten equal range(e.g. 1-10, 11-20, 21-30..etc.) and to plot a bar chart like this:

[image: Chart]

On the x-axis, I want to show the range and on the Y-axis the sum of corresponding values of rows in that range from column ['V'] using pandas and matplotlib.

```
I    R  V   C   D
27  1   21  13  16
89  1   5   27  10
80  1   9   21  10
64  2   20  7   26
65  2   29  11  17
5   2   4   27  3
48  3   26  7   17
16  4   11  28  12
66  4   29  7   18
71  4   20  3   18
43  4   21  10  26
76  4   22  9   5
53  4   10  26  5
96  4   12  27  14
44  4   16  25  19
24  5   27  15  26
13  6   8   15  18
95  6   23  24  28
33  7   7   27  3
11  7   26  10  1
93  7   11  12  4
4   7   14  5   3
97  8   1   20  26
28  8   2   6   8
52  8   29  12  13
67  8   14  1   23
77  9   26  9   23
78  9   7   24  19
45  9   11  26  13
73  11  4   28  20
2   11  14  14  2
57  11  17  19  23
99  12  9   14  22
72  12  2   17  19
25  12  9   24  4
69  12  1   14  1
79  12  4   12  7
94  13  14  26  8
60  13  15  27  1
42  13  22  6   2
49  13  12  24  11
6   13  11  10  4
21  14  20  19  24
38  14  19  6   27
62  14  21  9   16
61  14  19  26  12
81  14  18  24  18
22  14  4   27  26
7   14  12  1   19
68  15  21  27  14
58  15  27  3   7
59  16  27  26  1
56  16  4   15  17
55  16  7   5   10
0   16  26  25  17
17  18  10  28  21
1   18  13  20  1
50  19  13  10  17
83  19  25  14  8
14  19  17  13  24
91  19  15  2   24
36  19  7   26  4
90  19  20  28  3
26  19  5   15  5
84  19  11  26  28
8   19  6   13  14
98  20  2   23  4
3   20  18  17  5
51  20  6   22  18
92  21  27  22  11
35  21  1   20  14
47  21  18  22  12
46  21  5   22  20
85  21  26  22  20
75  22  14  11  17
70  22  23  10  25
18  22  16  18  24
30  22  29  22  9
32  23  6   9   9
31  23  29  6   9
20  23  24  4   5
41  23  12  6   16
82  24  5   4   7
19  24  3   15  4
74  24  25  28  19
63  24  5   6   9
54  25  7   9   23
12  27  26  6   21
37  27  15  2   5
23  28  3   5   6
88  28  8   3   13
9   28  10  20  19
10  28  13  27  25
40  28  8   27  16
15  28  1   13  26
29  28  14  11  16
87  28  6   19  10
86  29  15  9   25
34  29  13  25  29
39  29  14  2   25
​
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is how I have achieved what I was asking (Suggestions for improvement most welcome)

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd


data=np.random.randint(1, 30, (100, 4)) # create numpy array with random integer between 1 and 30.
df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns=list('RVCD')) #create Data frame 
bins=[1, 5, 10, 20, 30,40]
data1=df.groupby([pd.cut(df.R,bins).astype(str)])[['V']].sum().reset_index()
data1=data1.set_index('R')
data1.plot.bar(xlabel='Range of "R"', ylabel='Sum of "V" in the range', rot=0)
plt.show()
```

[Here is my Bar graph](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BcJFd.png)